# Compare two vectors of unequal lengths to get a logical array

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization

I need to vectorize the following code:

```
a = [1 2 3 2 3 1];
b = [1 2 3];

for i = 1:length(a)
    for j = 1:length(b)
        r(i, j) = (a(i) == b(j));
    end
end
```

The output r should be a logical array:

```
 1     0     0
 0     1     0
 0     0     1
 0     1     0
 0     0     1
 1     0     0
```

The closest I can get is:

```
for j = 1:length(b)
    r(:, j) = (a == b(j));
end
```

Iterating through the shorter vector is obviously more efficient as it generates fewer for iterations. The correct solution should have no for-loops whatsoever.

Is this possible in MATLAB/Octave?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html).

```
bsxfun(@eq,b,a')

ans =

     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
     1     0     0
```

Answer (score 3):

`bsxfun(@eq, a', b)`